# how to connect circular doubly-linked lists

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

Consider, I have given 2 items of the circular doubly-linked lists A and B. I want to implement a function which connects both of the lists.

This task is simple. However, I want to handle the case where A and B are the members of the same linked list. In this case it would just do nothing. Is it possible to implement it in O(1)? Do I need to check whether A and B are from the same list first? Or can I somehow magically swap/mix the pointers?

IMO it is not possible, but I'm unable to prove it.

thanks

Comment: it all depends on what fields does a member of a linked list have. If its only a pointer to next and previous than it is not possible to do it in O(1)

Comment: It contains just next and prev pointer. And I think, you're true, it isn't possible, however, I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can. Being curious myself, I sketched an implementation in Java. Assuming a linked list as follows

```
public class CLinkedList {

    class Node {
        Node prev, next;
        int val;

        public Node(int v) {
            val = v;
        }
    }

    Node s;

    public CLinkedList(Node node) {
        s = node;
    }

    void traverse() {
        if (s == null)
            return;

        Node n = s;
        do {
            System.out.println(n.val);
            n = n.next;
        } while (n != s);
    }
    ...
}
```

a merging method would look like

```
void join(CLinkedList list) {
    Node prev = list.s.prev;
    Node sprev = s.prev;

    prev.next = s;
    sprev.next = list.s;
    s.prev = prev;
    list.s.prev = sprev; 
}
```

which works just fine when the lists are different.

If they're not, all this does is just split the original list into two perfectly valid, *different* linked lists. All you should do is just join them again.

**Edit**: The `join` method joins (lol) two lists if they are different or (contrary to its name) splits the list if the nodes belong to the same list. Applying `join` twice thus has no effect, indeed. But you can make use of this property in other ways. The method below works fine:

```
public void merge(CLinkedList list) {
    CLinkedList nList = new CLinkedList(s.next);
    join(nList);
    nList.join(list);
    join(nList);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CLinkedList list = new CLinkedList(new int[] {1,2,3});
    CLinkedList nlist = new CLinkedList(list.s.next);
    list.merge(nlist);
    list.traverse();
}
```

Still O(1) :) Keeping the small disclaimer - not the best quality code, but you get the picture.

Comment: nice try, but what if they are from the different lists? First join would join them second would split them again. :-) Whatever... +1 :-D